# Get size of dynamically resizing Image in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an AsyncImage with the modifiers .resizable() and .scaledToFit()

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: urlToImage)) { image in
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                } placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                }
```

I want to put another Image on top of it. The size of the second Image needs to be computed from the size of the first Image.

So is it possible to get width and height of the first Image?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59621970/12299030?

Comment: After some modifications to the code it did. Thanks!