# Centering Item Inside Horizontal Stack with left and right views doesn't work with DatePicker

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

There was a similar question [Center Item Inside Horizontal Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59517327/1820553) that I followed the Asperi's basic answer that suited for me ( other answer did not worked, too).

```swift
struct HeaderTestView: View {
    
    @State private var currentDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.left.fill")
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.right.fill")
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Title")

                DatePicker("Date", selection: $currentDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Center Item are a Text and a DatePicker, everything works as expected until the date picker is placed. The title of DatePicker is placed on the left and date is placed on the right.

Without  the DatePicker

[image]

With the DatePicker

[image]

Any idea to solve this beautifully so that a Text and a DatePicker are close on the center while there are two HStacks that are adjested to on the left and right

Comment: As, I understand the DatePicker wants as much as space as possible, adding a `.frame(width:300)` can make the HStack on the center. This is a temprory solution for me, since the size of the title can be change..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.fixedSize()` to the `HStack` containing the `Text` view and `DatePicker`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var currentDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.left.fill")
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.right.fill")
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Title")
                
                DatePicker("Date", selection: $currentDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
            }
            .fixedSize()  // here
        }
    }
}
```

or add `.fixedSize()` to the `DatePicker`.

Comment: Yes, That was what I was looking, thanks. Now, I see that it is for all Views